# CSS - Why are some elements not appearing in the print preview window?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, printing

I'm building a web-based retail signage program using Vue.js. Once the user makes the signs, they need to be printed out. If there are more than 10 signs queued up to be printed, older signs begin to not show up in the print preview window.

I've confirmed that the application works as expected up until there are more than 10 signs. I've tried removing signs to make there only be 10 on the page, but since the page doesn't readjust sign positioning, it doesn't do anything.

Vue.js:

```
<div id="print-queue" v-title="title">
    <modal></modal>
    <confirm-dialog></confirm-dialog>
    <div class="queue-left">
        <div v-for="(sign, i) in signsLeft" :key="i">
            <sign
            :manufacturer="sign.manufacturer"
            :model="sign.model"
            :carrier="sign.carrier"
            :capacity="sign.capacity"
            :price=Number(sign.price)
            :comment="sign.comments"
            :sku="sign.sku"
            removable
            ></sign>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="queue-right">
        <div v-for="(sign, i) in signsRight" :key="i">
            <sign
                    :manufacturer="sign.manufacturer"
                    :model="sign.model"
                    :carrier="sign.carrier"
                    :capacity="sign.capacity"
                    :price=Number(sign.price)
                    :comment="sign.comments"
                    :sku="sign.sku"
                    removable
            ></sign>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the variables that it uses. Pretty basic.

```
    data() {
        return {
            title: 'Print Queue', // Sets the text that appears in the tab
            signsLeft: [],
            signsRight: []
        }
    },
```

CSS:

```
.queue-left {
    display: table;
    float: left;
}

.queue-right {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    right: 2px;
}

@media print {

    /* This correctly spaces the signs so that they align with the perforations on the paper */
    #print-queue {
        padding-top: 0.81em;
        padding-left: 2.3em;
    }

    .sign-preview *{
        visibility: visible!important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    .container {
        padding: 32px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sign-delete {
        display: none;
    }

    tr:not(#comment-cell):hover {
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    ::webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #fff!important;
    }
}
```

Expected: The user should be able to print any number of signs. Signs in excess of 10 should appear on another page.

Actual: Once there are more than 10 signs, any new signs get pushed off the first page and do not appear in the print preview.

Comment: Can you possibly post the implementation of this `sign` component or make a fiddle?